# PyFlink datastream API support for windowing

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

Does Apache Flink's Python SDK ([PyFlink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/python/)) Datastream API support operators like Windowing? Whatever examples I have seen so far for Windowing with PyFlink, all use the Table API. The [Datastream API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/stream/operators/windows.html) does support these operators, but looks like these are not available via PyFlink yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, PyFlink doesn't yet support the DataStream window API. Follow [FLINK-21842](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-21842) to track progress on this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I guess Flink allows Table and Datastream APIs to be mixed, so Windowing can be achieved by using the corresponding Table APIs.